# MySQL: How to escape backslashes in outfile?

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I want to output some fields into file using this query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(CHAR(13), CHAR(9), '{"name":"', name, '",'),
            CONCAT('"id":', CAST(rid AS UNSIGNED), '}')
        ),
    CHAR(13), ']')
AS json FROM `role`
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/roles.json'
```

In output file I'm getting something like this:

```
[
\       {"name":"anonymous user","rid":1},
\       {"name":"authenticated user","rid":2},
\       {"name":"admin","rid":3},
\       {"name":"moderator","rid":4}
]
```

As you can see, newlines (`char(13)`) has no backslashes, but tab characters (`char(9)`) has. How can I get rid of them?

**UPDATE**
Sundar G gave me a cue, so I modified the query to this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('"name":', name),
    CONCAT('"rid":', rid)

INTO outfile '/tmp/roles.json'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '\t{' TERMINATED BY '},\n'

FROM `role`
```

I don't know why, but this syntax strips backslashes from output file:

```
       {"name":"anonymous user","rid":1},
       {"name":"authenticated user","rid":2},
       {"name":"admin","rid":3},
       {"name":"moderator","rid":4}
```

This is already pretty nice output, but I also would like to add opening and closing square brackets at the beginning and at the end of the file. Can I do this by means of MySQL syntax or I have to do that manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [`SELECT ... INTO` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html):

> The syntax for the ***`export_options`*** part of the statement consists of the same `FIELDS` and `LINES` clauses that are used with the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) statement. See [Section 13.2.6, “`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html), for information about the `FIELDS` and `LINES` clauses, including their default values and permissible values.

That referenced page says:

> If you specify no `FIELDS` or `LINES` clause, the defaults are the same as if you had written this:
>
> ```
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
> ```

and later explains:

> For output, if the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character is not empty, it is used to prefix the following characters on output:
>
> - The `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character
> - The `FIELDS [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY` character
> - The first character of the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY` values
> - ASCII `0` (what is actually written following the escape character is ASCII “`0`”, not a zero-valued byte)
>
> If the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character is empty, no characters are escaped and `NULL` is output as `NULL`, not `\N`. It is probably not a good idea to specify an empty escape character, particularly if field values in your data contain any of the characters in the list just given.

Therefore, since you have not explicitly specifying a `FIELDS` clause, any occurrences of the default `TERMINATED BY` character (i.e. tab) within a field will be escaped by the default `ESCAPED BY` character (i.e. backslash): so the tab character that you are creating gets so escaped.  To avoid that, explicitly specify either a different field termination character or use the empty string as the escape character.

However, you should also note that the size of your results will be limited by [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).  Perhaps a better option would be:

```
SELECT json FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS sort_col, '[' AS json
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, CONCAT('\t{"name":', QUOTE(name), ',"id":', CAST(rid AS UNSIGNED), '}')
  FROM   role
UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ']'
) t
ORDER BY sort_col
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/roles.json' FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''
```

Comment: **eggyal**, thank you for such detailed answer and neat solution!

Comment: @VladT.: On looking again I noticed a couple of errors, which I have correct above. Most notably, I saw in [`UNION` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) that "*Only the last `SELECT` statement can use `INTO OUTFILE`. (However, the entire `UNION` result is written to the file.)*", so my subquery was superfluous and unnecessary. Furthermore, "*To cause rows in a `UNION` result to consist of the sets of rows retrieved by each `SELECT` one after the other, select an additional column in each `SELECT` to use as a sort column and add an `ORDER BY` following the last `SELECT`*".

Comment: Previous query also worked for me, but thanks a lot for correction :-)

Comment: I tried to use corrected query, but got an error that seems has to do with [this bug (link)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34665). Can you suggest how to correctly use `INTO OUTFILE` with multiple `UNION`'s?

Comment: Have tried a moment ago: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL SELECT 2, CONCAT('\t{"name":', QUOTE(name), ',"rid":', CAST(rid AS ' at line 2`, using MySQL 5.1

Comment: @VladT.: And, to confirm, what happens if you omit the parentheses around the first `UNION`?

Comment: Getting error `near 'INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/roles.json' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '' at line 8`

Comment: @VladT.: Okay, in that case it seems that the subquery I originally had is necessary after all.  However, it is important to include the new `ORDER BY` clause as otherwise the `UNION` results are not guaranteed to be in the desired order.  See my latest update for (I hope!) the final version.

Comment: Yes, final version is working. Thank you again for having time to help me. You saved lots of my time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query like
SELECT your_fields
INTO outfile '/path/file' fields enclosed by '"' terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
FROM table; 
hope this works..

Comment: It really strips backslashes, thank you. But how do I get opening and closing square brackets?