# MySQL: Unexpected result with CONCAT strings with tab

Tags: mysql

I want to concatenate a couple of string columns using `\t` as separator and write the output to a file. The `CONCAT` alone seems to work fine.

```
SELECT CONCAT('A', '\t', 'B', '\t', 'C');
+-----------------------------------+
| CONCAT('A', '\t', 'B', '\t', 'C') |
+-----------------------------------+
| A     B     C                     |
+-----------------------------------+
```

However, when I try to write to a file using

```
SELECT CONCAT('A', '\t', 'B', '\t', 'C') INTO OUTFILE 'tmp/test.txt';
```

The file content looks like that, i.e., with an additional backlash before the tab:

```
A\      B\      C
```

How can I get rid of that backslash?

Comment: Why would you not use FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  ?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, for my case this will work just fine. It's just that I would like to understand that behavior in general. It seems rather unintuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that FIELDS ESCAPED BY '' gets rid of those backslashes.

I got that from this answer: [mysql-how-to-escape-backslashes-in-outfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136551/mysql-how-to-escape-backslashes-in-outfile)

And now that I found it I realise that I can also use P.Salmon's answer. No need to concatenate in the select.